# How to take stream of integers as an input in python just like as we do in c++?

Tags: python

[image: here is sample test case for input]

**c++ code**

```
while( cin >> variable)
 {
   //your code
 }
```

I want to convert this code into python, 
input is stream of integers like:

Comment: In Python3 you could use input method `variable = int(input("Put input of sth here"))`

Comment: I have to take many integers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the same in python you can catch an `EOFError`, e.g.:

```
while True:
    try:
        variable = int(input())
    except EOFError:
        break
    # your code
```

You can manually terminate the list of inputs with `Ctrl-D` or it will automatically terminate if you pipe in the input, e.g. `cat nums | myscript.py`

In Py 3.8 with assignment expressions you can change this to

```
try:
    while variable := int(input()):
        <do-something-with-variable)
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Or suppressing the exception with a context manager:

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(EOFError):
    while variable := int(input()):
        <do-something-with-variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
s=input("Enter: ")
s=[int(x) for x in s.split()]
```

`input()` will return a string version of the input. `split()` is applied on this string with space as delimiter.

Each element of the list returned by `split()` is converted to an integer with `int()`.

Edit:

To accept input till EOF, you could do

```
import sys
s=sys.stdin.read()
if(s[-1]=='\n'):
    s=s[:-1]
s=[int(x) for x in s.split()]
```

Comment: numbers are separated by new line, in that case it is not working

Comment: its depend on user when ever he stop to giving input

Comment: see the question , i have updated, an image of the sample test cases is also provided

Comment: got the answer, see in answer section

Comment: @TheSohan I dug up something as well. But I think the other answer is more appropriate.